# JBPM-Console-NG 6.1.0 User Not Authorized

Tags: jboss, jbpm

I downloaded the jbpm-console-ng from github and built it. I then went to the distribution wars folder and done the next build. I then took the distribution war for as-7 and deployed it. Next i created my own user and added admin, manager, user, IT etc to its roles.

When I go to log in I can't because I'm not authorized? The same thing happens with the default users e.g. salaboy

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the steps in the documentation to create the users and add the roles? 
Are you using jboss as 7.1.1?

Comment: yeah it turns out you can't just build from source and deploy. If you are meant to its bugged in versions below 6.2.0. I had to go into web.xml and specify security roles and authentication users. By default it will only let the user role 'jbpm-console-user' have access. I changed this to what I wanted and it worked.